# What is the UIView called with editing and deleting?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios, uiview

Is there a pre-made view that is a UITableView but you can edit each cell and when you slide your finger across you can delete it. And in the UINavigationBar on the top there is an item on the right that is a "+" sign for adding to the table? That sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be 1000's of examples that have editable UITableViews. You can check over the Apple DOcumentation, or search Google for examples.

Both creating the [+] and swipe-to-delete are easily implemented on a UITableView. It really just matters what you add and how you add information to the UITableView.

Check out the iOS Reference Library, there are quite a few examples of how to do this, specifically, the [CoreDataBooks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html) example. It has exactly what you are looking for.